# Having trouble understanding the MAX-CUT problem

Tags: algorithm, np, np-hard

I'm having trouble understanding the general idea behind the MAX-CUT problem. Consider the graph below.

[image]

The MAX-CUT asks us to find the cut that maximizes the number of edges that it touches. I can trivially draw this.

[image]

I don't get what the problem is? For any graph, it's trivial for me to find the line that crosses all the edges. Am I misunderstanding the problem?

EDIT:

In response to David, here's a picture of my version of MAX-CUT where we end on an ending vertex

[image]

Comment: I think the idea is that each line should be crossed only once, although I didn't find a definition that states it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [formal definition of MAX-CUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut) is to find a set of vertices `S` to maximize the number of edges with exactly one endpoint in `S`. Graphically, this means drawing a simple closed curve and counting only the number of edges crossed an odd number of times.

Comment: What's an endpoint? Sorry, I've been looking at quite a bit of powerpoints and I still don't get it.

Comment: @echo One of the two dots that the edge connects.

Comment: I updated the question description to have an image of what I think you mean

Answer (score 0):

you are misunderstanding the problem. The goal is to separate the vertices in a bipartite set, meaning into two groups. As an example, look at the bottom and top left vertices, which you disconnected with your cut. These two vertices must therefore be in a different sets. At the same time both of these vertices are disconnected from the vertex in the middle left. This would mean that this vertex also has to be in a different group, which is impossible.

Cutting the edges means assigning the vertices to opposite groups. But you can't assign all vertices to opposite groups because there are only two groups you can choose from.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).